# How to get user local time at Page_Load

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, timezone

I have a web page written in ASP.NET and I need to retrieve the end user's local time at `Page_Load`. I thought about using Javascript to get the local time (by using `new Date()`) but the problem is that the script is run after the server events.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

EDIT: My page is quite complex: it displays a chart with lots of calculated fields from a database, object/fields selection lists, etc; The customer now requested that it should  consider the user's timezone and that the timezone should be determined automatically by the web page. The user date is important to determine the chart interval (which day to display data on).
Data loading (since it is so complicated) is done in both `Page_Load` and `Page_PreRender`. Giving up these events would require a full page rewrite.

FINAL SOLUTION INSPIRED BY ANSWER:
Here is how I solved the problem eventually. I am keeping the local date in a cookie. Here is the method that sets the cookie:

```
function SetLocalDateCookie() {
    var cookieName = 'LOCALDATE';
    var localDate = new Date();
    var realMonth = localDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var localDateString = localDate.getFullYear() + "/" + realMonth + "/" + localDate.getDate();
    setCookie(cookieName, localDateString, 2);
    try {
        var exdate = new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + 2);
        document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + escape(localDateString) + ";expires=" + exdate.toGMTString();
    }
    catch (e)
    { }
}
```

In my Master page I call this method on `$(document).ready`. 
On the page where I use this cookie I added the following code to `Page_Init`:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CookieHandler.Instance.GetCookie(CookieKeys.LocalDate)))
{
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Write(@"<form id='local' method='post' name='local'>
                        <script type='text/javascript'>
                            SetLocalDateCookie();
                            document.getElementById('local').submit();
                        </script>
                    </form>");
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Then I can just use the cookie value in the C# code.
Thank you for your answers/comments!

Comment: You want the user's local time before your server events have been ran?

Comment: I also thought about using a cookie...but its value would need to be constantly updated (it has to hold a datetime); also what happens the first time the page is loaded and the cookie is not set?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Why wouldn't the initial page load date/time suffice?

Comment: What do you need this local date time for? there may be another way to accomplish your end goal

Comment: I need the local time to know the user's date at his time zone

Comment: Yes, I got that part. But why do you need it so soon? What do you plan on using it for? What server events need to use it and why? At the moment the only thing I can think of is that you need it for display purposes on that page, but if that was the case you could just modify the display with javascript when the page loads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll explain a bit the following code and what lefts for you to do.

At the first request off this page, the code checks if the LocalTime is not already stored in Session and if not it will write a form element, a hidden input and a javascript which will post that form with the local time. The response ends, so your report won't get the chance to be generated.

This submit will immediately create a POST request with the localTime set, then ASP .Net stores this POST value into the Session.

I also added a 302 redirect (Response.Redirect) to the original page, because of the usability. The User made initially a GET request, not a POST, so if he/she wants to refresh the page, the browser will reiterate the last action, which was that form.submit() and not the GET request.

You have now the local time. But you don't have to read it at every request since it can be compared to the UTC time, then with the server's time.

*edit:* You need to parse the UTC time into a DateTime, but probably it's easy to find the format, though might depend on the user's culture (not sure about this statement).

```
public ReportPage()
{
    this.Init += (o, e) =>
    {
        // if the local time is not saved yet in Session and the request has not posted the localTime
        if (Session["localTime"] == null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Params["localTime"]))
        {
            // then clear the content and write some html, a javascript code which submits the local time
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Write(@"<form id='local' method='post' name='local'>
                                <input type='hidden' id='localTime' name='localTime' />
                                <script type='text/javascript'>
                                    document.getElementById('localTime').value = new Date();
                                    document.getElementById('local').submit();
                                </script>
                            </form>");
            // 
            Response.Flush();

            // end the response so PageLoad, PagePreRender etc won't be executed
            Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            // if the request contains the localtime, then save it in Session
            if (Request.Params["localTime"] != null)
            {
                Session["localTime"] = Request.Params["localTime"];
                // and redirect back to the original url
                Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea. In the end I stored the local date in a cookie (the format is not important because I am saving the cookie in my own 'custom' format). I will detail my final solution in the question description.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this would be possible, you can't get the time off the client's local machine at server side.

The only way to achieve this would be using some javascript (as this is client based, so it will use the client's current date/time). But as you've stated, this will be after your server events have been ran, and your web page has been rendered into HTML and sent to the client.

One alternative would be to capture the clients time before the Post Back, but it wouldn't be possible to do this with an inital `Page_Load`.

Comment: in the http module you have many many events BEFORE PAGE LOAD.

Comment: @I dint see he wanted the client time. Thought Server Time. :) deleted.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Ah that makes sense now!

Comment: I agree with @Royi. You could register the javascript in the page's prerender event.

Comment: @JohnnyDropTables Royi is referring to server side date/time. He didn't realise the OP was after client side date/time.

Answer (score 0):

How about you place a hidden textbox on the page, attach an OnChange-eventhandler to it in C# and use an OnLoad JavaScript function to set the value to the value you need from the client?

Comment: Let me see if I understood: the actions that I perform in Page_Load will be moved in the OnChange event handler?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there isn't any way to get the users local time in the `Page_Load` event as that is executed on the server-side, and would therefore only be aware of the server's local date time.

To get the user's local time you would need to either execute an asynchronous call to the server upon the page loading in JavaScript, or store the local time in a hidden field and then read it on post-back.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use an interstitial page that contains nothing but the js to get local time and redirects to your current page passing the time information via query string or session variable or post